# Custom meta title for blogger blogspot posts

Tags: xml, blogger, blogspot

This is the blog post URL: https://thingsyouwishfor.blogspot.com/2018/04/raindrops-candy-pizza-1534-oz-435g.html

Currently the meta title format is set as "post title | blog title" therefore 'blog title' gets repeated on every blog posts meta tag.
Current code is this:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
 <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <title><data:blog.pageName/> | <data:blog.title/></title>
    <b:else/> 
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title> 
    </b:if>
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
```

I want to change the meta title format to "post title | post labels | first H2 tag"

Comment: I was expecting to get help on this. Please, if there is someone who can help me here, would really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Blogger Data Layout tags doesn't have any data tag that outputs the first H2 tag of a post. You may however try using the `data:blog.metaDescription` data tag.

On post pages `data:blog.metaDescription` outputs the search description text that you can enter when creating a post (on the right hand side panel, under "Search Description", when the option is enabled)

You will then have to make sure while making a post that your first H2's text is the search description (if you require the search description for a better purpose I do not recommend this)

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription == &quot;&quot;'>
        <title><data:blog.pageName/> | <data:blog.title/></title>
    <b:else/>
        <title><data:blog.pageName/> | <data:blog.title/> | <data:blog.metaDescription></title>
    </b:if>
<b:else/> 
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title> 
</b:if>
```

Inside the `<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>` condition we nested another condition that checks if there exists a meta tag or not, if not then it will not try to get it, else it will and separate the blog title and meta description with `|`.